# FFmpeg Command for Audio Files mix getting error

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Task:
      Mix Audio Files using FFmpeg in Android.

Error:

```
 [NULL @ 0xf6468400] Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -i '
 -i : Invalid argument
```

my Command:

```
  File m1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/m1.mp3"); 
  File m2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/m2.mp3");
 //m1,m2 are mp3 files
 //File outputDirectory2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/video1.mp3");

 String[] auidoMixCmd3={" -i ",""+m1.getPath()," -i ",""+m2.getPath()," -filter_complex [0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0 -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 0:-f mp3",outputDirectory2.getPath()};


 String[] auidoMixCmd2={" -i ",""+m1.getPath()," -i ",""+m2.getPath()," -i ",""+m1.getPath()," -filter_complex","\"[0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest\" -c:a libmp3lame -f mp3",outputDirectory2.getPath()};
```

I tried more than 100 times with differnt commands but i did not get any solutions.So many commands are in Stack overflow but getting same error.Please anyone help me out here.

Comment: Do you know which command is generating the error? Why do you have -i m1.getPath in Cmd2 twice?

Comment: Thanks for replay.Both and all tried my commands are giving  same error.In my mobile only 2 files but input need 3 files so i have given 2 times.I think it is not a problem.Is there any problem with file type or the need to provide any filter  specifications .

Comment: it's been a long time since I've used ffmpeg but I think the file types are fine. Are you sure you are specifying the params correctly? It says "-i" invalid and you are separating the "-i" and file paths into separate params. I think they are supposed to be together i.e. "-i " + m1.getPath(), "-i " + m2.getPath()...

Comment: @JeffR. anyway thanks for replay .I tried like this also but same error

Comment: `""+m1.getPath()` --> what are the two double-quotes for?

Comment: One other working code he given like this.so i tried this way,i tried with out that time also got same error

Comment: Then maybe it is the space you are added after the "-i". If you are separating the params into individual elements in the array and that is correct, then you shouldn't need to add the space in. You may need to show us how you are using those string arrays... in other words, can you show us the actual code calling ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a String Array you don't have to add the `+` symbol. Also, no need for the `""` before the `+` symbol.

Your command should look like this:

```
String[] auidoMixCmd3 = { "-i ", m1.getPath(), "-i ", m2.getPath(), "-filter_complex [0:a][1:a] amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0 -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 0 -f mp3", outputDirectory2.getPath()};
```

Comment: How to mix multiple times second audio with 5 seconds delay with overlay to first audio completion

Comment: Please accept my answer and ask a new question, I would be happy to help.

Comment: HI,can you write command for 3 or multiple inputs dynamically

Comment: You can have as many inputs as you like. Just add `"-i ", pathToFile`.

Comment: oh k no need to change filter_complex..?

Comment: `"-filter_complex [0:a][1:a][2:a] amix=inputs=3:duration=first:dropout_transition=0` and so on...

Comment: Thanks ,If i have reputation I would have given bunty for you.:)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: Actually i am sorry to ask again i have been working last 2 days with different commands for doing only one task.Approached with so many ways

Comment: My task is to overlay longest audio with another short video repeatedly upto longest audio over.Can you please help me out for that command